ER modelling for bus company
**

A bus company owns a number of buses. Each bus is allocated to a
particular route, although  some routes may have several buses. Each
route passes through a number of towns. One or more  drivers are
allocated to each stage of a route, which corresponds to a journey
through some or all  of the towns on a route. Some of the towns have a
depot where buses are kept – each bus always  returns to its allocated
depot at the end of the day.  Each of the buses is identified by its
registration number and can carry different numbers of  passengers,
since the vehicles vary in size and can be single or double-decked.
Each route is  identified by a route number and information is
available on the average number of passengers  carried per day for
each route. Drivers have an employee number, name, address, and
sometimes  a telephone number, and the names of the training courses
they have completed need to be stored.

**
I am required to create the ER modelling for this case study and I found out there are five entities in the text, which are bus, route, town, stage and depot.
enter image description here
the standard answer is shown on the image and it seems to be different from mine because it shows that entities, driver and town,create the relationship with the entity 'stage'. However,my anwser is: 'driver' and 'town' connect with 'route'. It's quite confused cause the text doesn't directly illustrate the relationship between stage, driver and town.Could someone explain with that?

Please show text information as text, not as an image

@Rohit Gupta I'm afraid it's difficult for me to present the modeling in text because the standard answer involves a Chen's notation diagram, which is represented using several geometric shapes.

Do you want to accept the diagram in the picture or do you want to change it?
